# Ordered set of tuples with different hash and sort keys

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures, hash, set

I have the following data structure (with example data):

```
edgeID (unique key) | timeStep (ordering key,            | value
                    |     can have multiple occurrences) | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
"edge1"             | 15                                 | 12.1
"edge3"             | 18                                 | 17.32
"edge2"             | 23                                 | 15.1
"edge5"             | 23                                 | 65.6
```

I want to be able to perform the following tasks efficiently on this structure:

- Add a new data entry with a `timeStep` higher than any other stored `timeStep`. If the `maxNumber` of data entries (eg. 20) is reached, the data entry with the lowest `timeStep` should be deleted.
- Merge two datasets keeping the `maxNumber` of data entries (eg. 20) highest `timeStemp` entries while of course keeping every `edgeID` at most once (in case there are two entries for one edge it should use the highest `timeStep` entry).

How do I implement this data structure in python?

I have tried one approach that works:

1. One dict that stores the data, one [SortedSet](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedset.html) that stores the keys according to the sort key:

   ```
   data = {}
   dataOrder = SortedSet(key=lambda x: data[x][0])
   maxDataSize = 20

   def addData(edgeID, dataTuple):
       if(len(data) >= maxDataSize):
           # remove oldest value
           key = dataOrder.pop(0)
           del data[key]
       # add
       data[edgeID] = dataTuple
       dataOrder.add(edgeID)

   addData("edge1", (15, 12.1))
   ```

   The downside of this approach is that I store the `edgeID` twice and that I always have to update both data structures.

I have tried one approach that does NOT work:

2. Only one [SortedSet](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedset.html) that stores the whole data and sorts according to the sort key:

   ```
   data = SortedSet(key=lambda x: x[1])
   maxDataSize = 20

   def addData(dataTuple):
       if(len(self.data) >= self.maxDataSize):
           # remove oldest value
           data.pop(0)
       # add
       data.add(dataTuple)

   addData(("edge1", 15, 12.1))
   ```

   The fact why this approach does not work is that it lets me enter the same `edgeID` twice with different `timeSteps` because (I think) it hashes the whole tuple and not just the `edgeID`. Unfortunately I cannot define a hash function in the `OrderedSet` constructor. This leads me to my third approach that I think must work:
3. Instead of using tuples as data entries I could define a class that implements the `__hash__()` function which would just return the `edgeID`. Then I could store objects of this class in an `OrderedSet`

Is this third approach really the best? What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `heapq` , sorted on timeStep.

look up: https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html

Essentially, python's heap is a min heap, so the smallest timestep will be stored on top of the heap and can be fetched in O(1).
Each time, before you enter an element into a heap, check if it has 20 entries or more...if there are >= 20 entries, heappop from the heap...this will remove the entry with the least timestamp...

you can coordinate this with another dict for faster fetch of other remaining entries based on a specific key you like

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm missing the "set" functionality with each edgeID only being allowed once. Or should I just check for existence of every key before I insert it? Then I could use a SortedList as well but I guess the benefit of using a heap would be the O(1) access of the lowest element. The point of my question is if there is a data structure that would help me avoid this "by-hand-check".

Comment: Right - unfortunately there is no concept of "references"/"pointers" to objects in python..so you'll need to maintain 2 data structs. 1) heap for getting lowest timestamp in o(1) and 2) a set for checking presence of entity (again o(1))...before you insert into heap check in set and when you pop from heap, make sure to remove from set...easy enough if you create a simple api (get/set) functionality for your own data struct and expose it to your users (other programs)